# publication safety, relaxed memory models and memcpy

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, x86, memory-model

I am trying to follow [this article](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/) in the section about publication safety. My case is no different than the trivial example in the article, but the "published" data is not a single value, but several fields in a `struct`. The publisher will write each field singularly, so by wrapping up each write with a store with `memory_order_release` I should be ok.

The consumer will first check with `memory_order_acquire` that the data is ready. Then, I'm tempted to use a `memcpy` to copy the entire published `struct` somewhere else (because that fits better into the rest of the pre-existing code), but this doesn't seem to be safe because I cannot specify the memory model. Is this just paranoia or can it be a serious problem?

Suggestions specific to amd64/x86 accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acquire semantics mean that loads later in program order won't get re-ordered before the barrier, regardless of what semantics you ask for on the later loads. So I believe that using memcpy to read the structure after an acquire barrier is safe.

Comment: so why the author of the article makes sure that both the load (and store) operations are atomic? Shouldn't it suffice that only the last one has an explicit memory model?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone, the comments on that blog post include some corrections. For instance, see [comments 20 and 21](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/#comment-3037) which point out that the variable `data` didn't need to be atomic. Especially, note Bartosz' comment that "the variable ready with its acquire/release semantics behaves like a mutex."